Set operator dynamically in a where/filter clause in a PySpark dataframe
I have this dataframe:
result = data_frame\
    .withColumn(f'{self.constraint_colname}_count', F.count(self.constraint_colname).over(w))\
    .withColumn(f'{self.constraint_colname}_occurences', F.lit(self.occurences).cast('long'))\
    .filter(F.col(f'{self.constraint_colname}_occurences') == 1)

on the filter clause, I want to set the == operator dynamically from the list<,>,=>,=<,!=
I tried:
operator = '=='
result = data_frame\
    .withColumn(f'{self.constraint_colname}_count', F.count(self.constraint_colname).over(w))\
    .withColumn(f'{self.constraint_colname}_occurences', F.lit(self.occurences).cast('long'))\
    .filter(F.col(f'{self.constraint_colname}_occurences') operator 1)

Is it possible to do it? I want to avoid implement if-elif statements

A way you could do it is by writing a function that does this.
from pyspark.sql.column import Column
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def compare_columns(col1, col2, operator: str):
    allowed_operator_list = ["<", ">", ">=", "<=", "!=", "=="]
    
    # Check if col1 and col2 are PySpark columns
    assert isinstance(col1, Column), "col1 must be a PySpark Column"
    assert isinstance(col2, Column), "col2 must be a PySpark Column"

    # Check if operator is in the allowed list
    assert operator in allowed_operator_list, "Operator not in allowed list."

    col_1_name = col1._jc.toString()
    col_2_name = col2._jc.toString()

    result_function = eval(f"col('{col_1_name}') {operator} col('{col_2_name}')")
    return result_function

# usage:
df.select(compare_columns(col("col1"), col("col2"), "=="))

In general, you should be careful with the eval function, as this can evaluate any code, so I am not sure I would recommend this.
Alternatively, arguably better, would be to do the following. But you have to implement every choice you want. And it seemed you wanted to avoid such a thing.
from pyspark.sql.column import Column
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def compare_columns(col1, col2, operator: str):
    allowed_operator_list = ["<", ">", ">=", "<=", "!=", "=="]
    
    # Check if col1 and col2 are PySpark columns
    assert isinstance(col1, Column), "col1 must be a PySpark Column"
    assert isinstance(col2, Column), "col2 must be a PySpark Column"

    # Check if operator is in the allowed list
    assert operator in allowed_operator_list, "Operator not in allowed list."

    # Using a dictionary to mimic switch-case behavior
    operations = {
        "==": col1 == col2,
        "<": col1 < col2,
        ">": col1 > col2,
        ">=": col1 >= col2,
        "<=": col1 <= col2,
        "!=": col1 != col2,
    }

    return operations[operator]



You can use SQL expression as the filter condition, and then do the regular Python variable interpolations within a string:
operator = '=='
result = data_frame\
    .....\
    .filter(f"`{self.constraint_colname}_occurences` {operator} 1")

make sure to enclose the column name with back-ticks so that the SQL expression works for columns with name containing non-words characters.
